# Relationship between $\langle \nabla f(\overline{x}), x - \overline{x}\rangle > 0$ and the the minimality of $\overline{x}$.

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Say $f$ is a differentiable function over a convex set $X$ with $\langle \nabla f(\overline{x}), x - \overline{x}\rangle > 0$ for all $x, \overline{x} \in X$ such that $x \neq \overline{x}$. Can we conclude from this alone that $\overline{x}$ is a local minimum? Certainly, if $f$ were pseudoconvex, this would hold trivially. However, I suspect that the strict inequality here may imply that $\overline{x}$ is indeed a local minimum

Comment: Did you mean $ \langle \nabla f(\bar{x}), x - \bar{x} \rangle $? What you wrote doesn't make sense unless $x, \bar{x}$ are scalars.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I misspelled nabla and didn't catch it.

Comment: Note that this condition implies that $\bar x$ is a boundary point of $X$.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you meant that $\langle \nabla f(\bar{x}), x - \bar{x}\rangle > 0, \forall x \neq \bar{x}$, this should imply a local minimum. From the differentiability of $f$, you know that near $\bar{x}$:

$$
f(x) = f(\bar{x}) + \langle \nabla f(\bar{x}), x - \bar{x} \rangle + o(\| x - \bar{x}\|),
$$

where $o(\| x - \bar{x} \|)$ is a term that satisfies
$
\lim_{x \to \bar{x}} \frac{o(\| x-\bar{x}\|)}{\| x - \bar{x}\|} = 0.
$
Then, assuming that $\forall \epsilon > 0$, there is a $x$ with $f(x) < f(\bar{x})$ and $\| x - \bar{x} \| < \epsilon$ (i.e. $\bar{x}$ is not a local minimum), you should
be able to derive a contradiction for a sufficiently small $\epsilon$.

Comment: I think you are assuming that $f$ is convex here, but that is not an assumption for this problem. Pseudoconvexity of $f$ is definitely a necessary assumption to make for the above to hold, so I do not think that $\bar{x}$ is a local minimum. But I cannot come up with a counterexample.

Comment: No, I'm not assuming convexity. The identity I wrote about $f(x)$ comes from the Taylor expansion of $f$ and the fact that it's differentiable. In fact, if $f$ were convex, you would not need the strict inequality for your claim.

Comment: Right. However, using this idea, I think the function $f(x_1,x_2) = (x_1^2-x_1)(x_2^2-2x_1)$ gives a counterexample as $(0,0)$ is not a local minimum.

Comment: @playitright No it is not a counterexample, as $\nabla f(0)=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your patience with me! I think I finally have a solid intuition of what's happening here, and I think that $\bar{x}$ is only guaranteed to be a local minimum when $X$ is open. If $X$ is closed, then this is not necessarily true, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is closely related to the Frank-Wolfe algorithm to find an optimal solution of a convex program or a "stationary" point in nonconvex problems. The quantity that you defined is known as (negative) surrogate duality gap or in short gap function. A stationary point can be a local minimum, local maximum, or a point in the boundary of the feasible set. You can find a solid discussion on the gap function in [1] and the application of the FW algorithm for nonconvex problems in [2].

[1] Bertsekas, D. P. (1999). Nonlinear programming. Athena Scientific

[2] Lacoste-Julien, S. (2016). Convergence rate of Frank Wolfe for non-convex objectives. arXiv:1607.00345